# RegEx for capturing ID numbers in URLs

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, regex-group

I want to catch IDs in the URLs with `preg_match`.

#### Regex:

```
/news.[a-z0-9A-Z_ -]*.?(\d+).?(?:page)?.?([0-9]+)?\.html
```

I want to catch (\d+) of the url right?

#### URL

```
http://localhost/news/content-287.html
```

#### Current Output

==> preg_match catch this:

```
Array:
  0 => string '/news/content-287.html' (length=22)
  1 => string '7' (length=1)
```

How do I solve this problem?

EDIT :

Ideally i would like an url who can be like this :

/news/title-is/page=2.html    And catch the title id and the page number...

:D Thanks emma

Answer (score 0):

You might want to simplify your expression. For example, here we can simply use capturing groups to target your desired IDs in the URLs. Maybe, this expression would suffice:

```
\/news\/([a-z-]+)([0-9]+)\.html
```

which you can additionally add/reduce its boundaries, if you want. For instance you can add any other chars, which might come before the IDs in this group `([a-z-]+)`, then your expression changes to:

```
\/news\/([a-z-\/=]+)([0-9]+)\.html
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0vMCcR/1).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Code

```
$pattern = '/\/news\/([a-z-\/=\?]+)([0-9]+)\.html/is';
$subject = 'http://localhost/news/content/title-id/id=287.html';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "/news/content/title-id/id=287.html"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "content/title-id/id="
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "287"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that answer ! What if my url is sometimes /news/title-id/page=2.html and sometimes without the /page extension 'cause i'll need to catch the id of the page too...

Comment: So preg_match not only catching what is on () ?

Comment: edited :D Sorry i'm new here trying to get how it works ^^